# Substitute user mid-Bash-script & continue running commands (Mac OSX)

Tags: arrays, macos, bash, unix, keychain

I'm building two scripts which combined will fully uninstall a program (Microsoft Lync) on Mac OS X. I need to be able to swap from an account with root access (this account initially executes the first script) to the user whom is currently logged in.


This is necessary because the second script needs to be executed not only by the logged-in user, but from said user's shell. The two scripts are name `Uninstall1.sh` and `Uninstall2.sh` in this example.


Uninstall1.sh (executed by root user):

```
#!/bin/bash

#commands ran by root user

function rootCMDs () {

pkill Lync
rm -rf /Applications/Microsoft\ Lync.app
killall cfprefsd

swapUser

}

function swapUser () {

currentUser=$(who | grep console | grep -v _mbsetupuser | grep -v root | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1)

cp /<directory>/Uninstall2.sh${currentUser}

su -l ${currentUser} -c "<directory>/{currentUser}/testScript.sh";
```

`<directory>` actually declared in the scripts, but for the sake of privacy I've excluded it.

In the above script, I run some basic commands as the root user to remove the app to the trash, and kill cfprefsd to prevent having to reboot the machine. I then call the `swapUser` function, which dynamically identifies the current user account signed into and assigns this to the variable `currentUser` (in this case within our environment, it's safe to assume only one user is logged into the computer at a time). I'm not sure whether or not I'll need the `cp directory/Uninstall2.sh` portion yet, but this is intended to solve a different problem.


The main problem is getting the script to properly handle the `su` command. I use the `-l` flag to simulate a user login, which is necessary because this not only substitutes to the user account which is logged into, but it launches a new shell as said user. I need to use `-l` because OS X doesn't allow modifying another user's keychain from an admin account (the admin account in question has root access, but isn't nor does it switch to root). `-c` is intended to execute the copied script, which is as follows:


Uninstall2.sh (needs to be executed by the locally logged-in user):

```
#!/bin/bash


function rmFiles () {
    # rm -rf commands
    # rm -rf commands

certHandler1
}


function certHandler1 () {

myCert=($(security dump-keychain | grep <string> | grep alis | sed -e 's/"alis"<blob>="//' | sed -e 's/"//'))
cLen=${#myCert[@]} # Count the amount of items in the array; there are usually duplicates

for ((i = 0;
      i < ${cLen};
      i++));
      do security delete-certificate -c ${myCert[$i]};
done

certHandler2
}


function certHandler2 () {

# Derive the name of, and delete Keychain items related to Microsoft Lync.

myAccount=$(security dump-keychain | grep KeyContainer | grep acct | sed -e 's/"acct"<blob>="//' | sed -e 's/"//')
   security delete-generic-password -a ${myAccount}

lyncPW=$(security dump-keychain | grep Microsoft\ Lync | sed -e 's/<blob>="//' | awk '{print $2, $3}' | sed -e 's/"//')
   security delete-generic-password -l "${lyncPW}"
}


rmFiles
```

In the above script, `rmFiles` kicks the script off by removing some files and directories from the user's `~/Library` directory. This works without a problem, assuming the `su` from `Uninstall1.sh` properly executes this second script using the local user's shell.


I then use `security dump-keychain` to dump the local user's shell, find a specific certificate, then assign all results to the `cLen` array (because there may be duplicates of this item in a user's keychain). Each item in the array is then deleted, after which a few more keychain items are dynamically found and deleted.


What I've been finding is that the first script will either properly `su` to the logged-in user which it finds, at which point the second script doesn't run at all. Or, the second script is ran as the root user and thus doesn't properly delete the keychain items from the logged-in user it's supposed to `su` to.


Sorry for the long post, thanks for reading, and I look forward to some light shed on this situation!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't run at all"? If you put `touch /tmp/some_unique_filename` as the first line in second script it doesn't get created when you use `su` in the first script? What do you get as output from the first script if you use `bash -cx 'second_script.sh'`? You have a typo here in the `cp` command above the `su` command? Is that in the original too?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - by 'doesn't run at all', I mean that a new shell is launched as the logged-in user, but in that situation none of the commands in the 2nd script run at all. The script ends after launching the new shell as the logged-in user. I'll try using `touch /tmp/filename` and see what kind of results I get. In regards to your suggestion to use `bash -cx 'second_script.sh'`, are you suggesting I substitute the `su -l ` command entirely for this `bash -cx` command?

Comment: When it "doesn't run at all" did you use `su -l` by itself? Because that will just run a shell as that user and not give it any commands. `su` in a script doesn't read later lines in the script. It runs itself and waits for the spawned shell process to exit and **then** the original script keeps executing. Sorry, misread the `-c` there. So add `set -x` to the start of the shell script to see what actually executes. But that sounds like it might not be the actual problem. What happens **exactly** with the scripts as written above?

Comment: The full `su` command I use is: `su -l ${currentUser} -c "path/to/script.sh"`. I've changed my script a lot by now so the results vary depending on what I had modified - I'll edit my post now to show you what's happening as of right now with the way my script is set-up.

Comment: Update - I got the `su -l ${currentUser} -c "bash /path/to/file.sh"` portion working! Using `bash` to execute the file seemed to do the trick. Thanks @EtanReisner! I do have another question though - what's the purpose of putting `touch /tmp/some_unique_filename` in the first line of the second script?

Comment: It was a test of whether the script ran at all. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revision**

I managed to find a way to achieve all that I am trying to do in a single bash script, rather than two. I did this by having the main script create another bash script in /tmp, then executing that as the local user. I'll provide it below to help anybody else whom may need this functionality:


Credit to the following source for the code on how to create another bash script within a bash script:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html - Example 19.8

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare the desired directory and file name of the script to be created. I chose /tmp because I want this file to be removed upon next start-up.
OUTFILE=/tmp/fileName.sh

(
cat <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash

# Remove user-local Microsoft Lync files and/or directories
function rmFiles () {

   rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.Lync
   rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Lync.plist
   rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/MicrosoftLync*
   rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Microsoft-Lync*
   rm -rf ~/Documents/Microsoft\ User\ Data/Microsoft\ Lync\ Data
   rm -rf ~/Documents/Microsoft\ User\ Data/Microsoft\ Lync\ History
   rm -f ~/Library/Keychains/OC_KeyContainer*

certHandler1
}


# Need to build in a loop that determines the count of the output to determine whether or not we need to build an array or use a simple variable.
# Some people have more than one 'PRIVATE_STRING' certificate items in their keychain - this will loop through and delete each one. This may or may not be necessary for other applications of this script.

function certHandler1 () {

# Replace 'PRIVATE_STRING' with whatever you're searching for in Keychain
myCert=($(security dump-keychain | grep PRIVATE_STRING | grep alis | sed -e 's/"alis"<blob>="//' | sed -e 's/"//'))
cLen=${#myCert[@]} # Count the amount of items in the array

   for ((i = 0;
        i < ${cLen};
        i++));
      do security delete-certificate -c ${myCert[$i]};
   done

certHandler2
}

function certHandler2 () {

# Derive the name of, then delete Keychain items related to Microsoft Lync.
myAccount=$(security dump-keychain | grep KeyContainer | grep acct | sed -e 's/"acct"<blob>="//' | sed -e 's/"//')
   security delete-generic-password -a ${myAccount}

lyncPW=$(security dump-keychain | grep Microsoft\ Lync | sed -e 's/<blob>="//' | awk '{print $2, $3}' | sed -e 's/"//')
   security delete-generic-password -l "${lyncPW}"

}

rmFiles


exit 0

EOF
) > $OUTFILE

# -----------------------------------------------------------

# Commands to be ran as root
function rootCMDs () {
 pkill Lync
 rm -rf /Applications/Microsoft\ Lync.app
 killall cfprefsd # killing cfprefsd mitigates the necessity to reboot the machine to clear cache.

 chainScript

}

function chainScript () {

if [ -f "$OUTFILE" ]
then
  # Make the file in /tmp executable. This is necessary for /tmp as a non-root user cannot access files in this directory.
  chmod 755 $OUTFILE
  # Dynamically identify the user currently logged in. This may need some tweaking if multiple User Accounts are logged into the same computer at once.
  currentUser=$(who | grep console | grep -v _mbsetupuser | grep -v root | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1);
  su -l ${currentUser} -c "bash /tmp/UninstallLync2.sh"

else
  echo "Problem in creating file: \"$OUTFILE\""
fi

}


#  This method also works for generating
#+ C programs, Perl programs, Python programs, Makefiles,
#+ and the like.

# Commence the domino effect.
rootCMDs

exit 0

# -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Cheers!

Comment: Does `scriptName.sh` have executable permissions? If not that would probably be why `-c` couldn't run it.

Comment: It did - I included `chmod +x /tmp/scriptName.sh` in the original `rootCMDs` function.

Comment: @EtanReisner I do have another question, though. Is it possible to do all of this in a single script, rather than breaking it into two? I'm thinking have the `su -l ${currentUser} -c "<command>"` somehow execute the entire contents of `script2.sh`, without it being in a separate script.

Comment: You can put the commands in the `-c` argument directly instead of having it run a script if you wanted to but that has quoting complications that probably aren't worth it. I'd double check that the executable permissions were set correctly because if they were then executing the script directly should work just fine.

Comment: Well, the reason this is complicated is because these two scripts will be pushed to machines via JAMF (a mobile device management suite). Scripts and applications ran via Self Service (a proprietary App Store, essentially, that we provide apps and settings using) - the items ran from Self Service are executed by a hidden JAMF Admin account that's created on each machine upon enrollment. On top of that, the policy is built in a way such that multiple scripts can run <before> or <after> one another - but this doesn't help with the fact that each script is executed by said JAMF account.